# Problem with the Image hosting server?

Tags: bug, images, error-message, uploader, server

As I understand images uploaded to stack exchange sites are stored in https://i.stack.imgur.com . I recently noticed image included posts having broken links.

When clicked on the link it gives the error

> This page isn’t working i.stack.imgur.com redirected you too many
>   times.

And ironically I can't put a screenshot here as well due to the same issue.

What has happened to image hosting server?

[image: broken image link]

Comment: @Glorfindel I searched before asking but that didn't come up. Anyways there's no valid answer posted there?

Comment: No, that means they're still working on it.

Comment: @Glorfindel fine, but a developer there could have easily posted an answer explaining that :/

Comment: @ETHER https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1026968807837970432

Comment: @Glorfindel got it, thanks.